# Using a while loop to check divisibility of a range of numbers

Tags: python, while-loop, jupyter, division

I am trying checking the divisibility of 5 and 7 for the numbers in the range from 1 to 41 using a `while` loop. I know that there are other options, such as a `for` loop, but I would like to understand how the code needs to be set up with a `while` loop. This is the code I wrote:

```
n = 1
m = 41

div = [5,7]

while(n<=m): 
    if n == 13:
        continue
    if n%div[0]==0 and n%div[1]==0:
        print(n, 'the number is divisible for both 5 and 7')    
    elif n%div[0]==0:
        print(n, 'the number is divisible for 5')    
    elif n%div[1]==0:
        print(n, 'the number is divisible for 7')
    else:
        print(n, 'is divisible for neither 5 or 7')
```

On the Jupyter session, it didn't return an error, but it takes a significant amount of time to process the output. Can someone tell me how to properly modify this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `continue` would block the while loop to go any further when `n == 13`.

Other than that, the code and algorithm are actually correct. You just forgot to set an incremental structure `(n+=1)`.

```
n = 1
m = 41

div = [5,7]

while(n<=m): 
    if n == 13:
        n+=1
    if n%div[0]==0 and n%div[1]==0:
        print(n, 'the number is divisible for both 5 and 7')    
    elif n%div[0]==0:
        print(n, 'the number is divisible for 5')    
    elif n%div[1]==0:
        print(n, 'the number is divisible for 7')
    else:
        print(n, 'is divisible for neither 5 or 7')
    n+=1
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually the loop is keeping to take time to execute the statements. Maybe be there is some problem I am not able to figure out. Do you any chance to test it?

Comment: I just ran the code in an online Python compiler and interpreter and it was really fast. Is there any more code in the program?

Comment: Really. Do you mind to share the output, please?

Comment: shure. here's a print of the code and output: https://ibb.co/2gHw6NM

Answer (score 3):

You need to increment `n` by adding:

```py
n += 1
```

at the bottom of the `while` loop. You also need to remove the `continue` statement at the top of the body of the `while` loop. Without these two fixes, the program will attempt to repeatedly check whether a number is divisible by 5 or 7 without ever terminating.

---

If you must skip a specific number, you should revise the `if` statement to look like the following:

```py
if n == 13:
    n += 1
    continue
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your code will never get out of the `while` loop. It will always be stuck in the while loop. What you need to rechange the `n` value in the while loop:

```py
n = 1
m = 41

div = [5,7]

while(n<=m): 
    if n == 13:
        n += 1
        continue
    if n%div[0]==0 and n%div[1]==0:
        print(n, 'the number is divisible for both 5 and 7')    
    elif n%div[0]==0:
        print(n, 'the number is divisible for 5')    
    elif n%div[1]==0:
        print(n, 'the number is divisible for 7')
    else:
        print(n, 'is divisible for neither 5 or 7')
    n += 1
```